# How can I recreate these tire treads from scratch by just using normal map?

Tags: texturing, uv, normals, normal-map

How may I recreate these tire treads by just using **normal map**? The height factor is not very important. It can look like the example in the second picture.

[image: tire treads]
[image]

Comment: you can model a series of cubes with the Array modifier, then bake and use the result on your tire?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.